# What do we call a person who walks into a ditch/trap himself without anyones provokation or enticing him

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

Without being careful, or may be with some arrogance, if a person walks into a troublesome situation, what are the phrases or words to describe him?

Comment: **Reckless** is probably the word you are looking for - without caution; careless. There's also **rash** - acting or done without careful consideration of the possible consequences, or even **impetuous**

Comment: Single-word requests should supply a real-world example sentence so those answering can determine the register.

Answer (score 1):

The Holy Bible names them **Simpleton** and **Naive**.

A prudent person foresees danger and takes precautions. The **simpleton** goes blindly on and suffers the consequences.